# Android default drawer activity/layout is laggy on my app

Tags: java, android, layout, drawerlayout

In my app i am using the drawer layout, the default one that you can take when you are creating a new activity.

However, its not smooth, its has a pretty big lag/breaks opening/closing the menu, im including here my MainActivity.java. I have searched around but didntt find anything.

This is my drawer layout:

[image]

Can this be fixed ?

```
    package com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.Activities;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.R;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.database.DAL;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.database.DBAccessMode;
import com.example.bugdroid.menuexe.database.DBContract;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private DAL dal;

    private TextView Nsintomas;

    private ImageButton Adicionar;
    private ImageButton VerRegistos;
    private ImageButton Calendario;
    private ImageButton Consultas;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Nsintomas = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Nsintomas);
        Adicionar = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addSintoma);
        VerRegistos = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnVerRegistos);
        Calendario = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnCalendario);
        Consultas = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnConsultas);

        // Pega na informação da tabela Reg_Sintomas

        dal = new DAL(this);
        dal.connect(DBAccessMode.READ);

        long returnval = dal.getTaskCount();
        Nsintomas.setText(String.valueOf(returnval));

        /* Cursor res = dal.selectALLFromRegSintomas();
        String regs = "";
        res.moveToFirst();
        while (!res.isAfterLast()) {
            regs += res.getInt(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas._ID));
            regs += " - ";
            regs += res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas.COL_Sintoma));
            regs += "\n";
            regs += res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas.COL_D_Inicio));
            regs += "\n";
            regs += res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas.COL_H_Inicio));
            regs += "\n";
            regs += res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas.COL_D_Fim));
            regs += "\n";
            regs += res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas.COL_H_Fim));
            regs += "\n";
            regs += res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Reg_sintomas.COL_Intensidade));
            regs += "\n";
            res.moveToNext();
        }*/

        Cursor res2 = dal.VerMedicacao();
        String xdxd = "";
        res2.moveToFirst();
        while (!res2.isAfterLast()) {
            xdxd += res2.getString(res2.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Sintoma_medicacao.COL_ID_sintoma));
            xdxd += "\n";
            xdxd += res2.getString(res2.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Sintoma_medicacao.COL_ID_medicacao));
            xdxd += "\n";
            res2.moveToNext();
        }

        //dal.disconnect();
        //TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.teste);
        //tv.setText(regs);

        Adicionar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, InsertFirstActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        VerRegistos.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // String frase = "O orlando";
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerRegsSintomas.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        Calendario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendario.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });
        Consultas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent arroz = new Intent(MainActivity.this, VerConsultas.class);
                startActivity(arroz);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }


    boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {

        }
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Prima a tecla outra vez para sair", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_export) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_defs) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_consultas) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
                    .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Nova Consulta")
                    .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Não esquecer de ir a esta consulta");
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_feed) {

        }
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```